# Choices for online video chatting? - WebRTC

Tags: video, webrtc

I am adding online video chatting in my web app.  I did some research on the available options:

1. [OpenTok](http://tokbox.com/opentok/) - Has Flash version and WebRTC version. The Flash version works in OSX but not Linux (tested in chrome), and the WebRTC version only supports Chrome (and still not even in Linux).
2. [WebRTC.io](https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io) - Supports multiple people in the same session. Works in both OSX and Linux, but only supports Chrome.
3. The AppRTC [demo](http://apprtc.appspot.com/) in [this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) - seems very promising, works in both Chrome and Firefox (both OSX and Linux). The only down side is the demo supports at most two people in the same session. Not sure if it is extensible to multiple people.

There are probably other better choices I am not aware of. Given the following requirements:

1. allows multiple people (>=2) to chat within the same session,
2. support Chrome and Firefox,
3. don't need to spend years to implement,

Are there any good alternatives that I can give a try?

Comment: If you're searching for libraries; there is RTCMultiConnection that highly simplifies each and everything! https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RTCMultiConnection Supports all WebRTC parts in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of options for this: some more suggestions [here](http://io13webrtc.appspot.com/#69).

It's also not that hard to roll your own using WebSocket for signalling. Socket.io on Node is a good way to implement this: I've written a [codelab](https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab/) that shows how. You might also want take a look at the [Signalmaster](https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster) and the [SimpleWebRTC](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/03/making-webrtc-simple-with-conversat-io/) client that goes with it.

As you mention, XHR + Channel API as per the [apprtc.appspot.com](http://apprtc.appspot.com) example is another option for signalling: code [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc-samples/source/browse/trunk/apprtc/).

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I work for vLine.**

You should take a look at vLine (https://vline.com). We support your requirements and provide a lot of additional features that you may find useful: https://vline.com/faq.